# How may I retain the variable name after get() in a loop?

Tags: r, for-loop

```
n <- 1000 
xcat <- sample(x=c("A","B", "C", "D", "E"), 
 size=n, replace=TRUE, prob=rep(1/5, 5))  #(a)
xcont<-rnorm(n,23,4)
dat<-data.frame(xcat,xcont)
for(i in 1:200){
assign(paste('x',i,sep=""),rnorm(n,2+i*2,i))
dat<-cbind(dat,get(paste('x',i,sep="")))
}
names(dat)[1:4]
[1] "xcat"                             "xcont"                            "get(paste(\"x\", i, sep = \"\"))" "get(paste(\"x\", i, sep = \"\"))"
```

The variable name in the dat is not what I want (get(paste(\"x\", i, sep = \"\"))" "get(paste(\"x\", i, sep = \"\"))). I want the names of x1, x2, x3 ...... How can I get the correct names for the data frame?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to create new variables, this should also work:

```
n <- 1000 
xcat <- sample(x = c("A","B", "C", "D", "E"), 
               size = n, replace = TRUE, prob = rep(1/5, 5))  #(a)
xcont <- rnorm(n, 23, 4)
dat <- data.frame(xcat, xcont)

for(i in 1:200){
  col_new <- paste0("x", i)
  dat[, col_new] <- rnorm(n, 2+i*2, i)
}
names(dat)[1:4]
```

Answer (score 0):

Name them "after the fact":

```
n <- 1000 
xcat <- sample(x=c("A","B", "C", "D", "E"), 
 size=n, replace=TRUE, prob=rep(1/5, 5))  
xcont<-rnorm(n,23,4)
dat<-data.frame(xcat,xcont)
for(i in 1:200){

dat<-cbind(dat, rnorm(n,2+i*2,i) )

}
names(dat)[3:202] <- paste('x',1:200,sep="")
names(dat)[1:4]
#[1] "xcat"  "xcont" "x1"    "x2"
```